# Login TypeError: Cannot read property '$exists' of undefined in couchbase using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase

Checking login id's are existing or not in couchbase database using node js. 
getting error like **TypeError: Cannot read property '$exists' of undefined**

I tried with only one condition means IF condition it is working fine but  i try  else condition means it will through error kindly help some one.

```
exports.login = function (req, res) {
   var socialdata = {socialId: req.body.socialId,logintype:req.body.logintype}
   if (socialdata) {
      users.find(socialdata, function (reqs, result) {
         if (result.length > 0) {
            jwt.sign(socialdata, process.env.secret, { expiresIn: '300000s' }, (err, token) => {
               res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', msg: 'Login Successfully...!', resCode: 200, login_token: token, });
            });
         } else {
            res.status(201).json({ status: 'success', msg: 'Welcome to Orange', resCode: 201 });
         }
      });
      }else {
      var userdata = {phonenumber: req.body.phonenumber,logintype: req.body.logintype}
      users.find(userdata, function (reqs, results) {
      if (results.length > 0) {
         jwt.sign(userdata, process.env.secret, { expiresIn: '300000s' }, (err, token) => {
            res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', msg: 'mobile Successfully...!', resCode: 200, login_token: token, });
         });
      } else {
         res.status(201).json({ status: 'success', msg: 'Welcome to Orange', resCode: 201 });
      }
   });
}
```

if request comes from social means it will be checking if condition otherwise it will check else condition. kildly help i'm new to node js

Comment: In the code what you have posted you didn't use `$exists` anywhere??

Comment: in this code i have posted two different login credentials suppose user login with social data means it will need to execute social data function otherwise it will run userdata function. i didn't use $exist function anywhere in this code

Comment: But your problem states that `Cannot read property '$exists' of undefined` means its trying property $exists of an Object. So in your code somewhere you are trying to read as follows `object.$exist` so its throwing the error, so that code is missing in your post